# How do i find the normal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the equations of the tangent and normal to $y = x^2$ at the point $H(2, 4)$.

I've already found the equation of the tangent which is $y=4x-4$
but I'm not sure how to approach the actual question, which is finding the normal.

Comment: are you facing difficulty in finding the y-intercepts, or the equation of normal ?

Comment: Difficulty finding the normal, i'll edit post right now

Comment: The normal will have slope $-\frac 14$ and pass through $(2,4)$. Can you write its equation now?

Comment: Yes, but what method should i use, point-slope or?

Comment: What's the relationship of slope of two perpendicular lines?

Comment: You have a point and the slope, it’s all you need.

Comment: @Xardous, Stop learning the name of method. You need a point, and the slope to find the equation of a line. That's all you need.

Comment: Ok. Figured it out, thanks yall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition a normal line is the line that touches a curve at one point and is perpendicular with the tangent line at the same point.

Thus, if your tangent line is $(y-y_1) = m (x-x_1) $,

The slope of a line $\perp$ to it is given by $-\frac{1}{m}$

Thus, to write the equation of a line with a slope of $-\frac{1}{m}$, passing through the same point $(x_1,y_1)$ :

$$(y-y_1) = -\frac{1}{m}(x-x_1)$$

In your example, slope of tangent $m$ is $4$. Thus slope of normal is $-\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus the line should be :

$$(y-4) = -\frac{1}{4}(x-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $f$ the equation of a tangent line at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is
$$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$
Similarly the normal line is
$$y=\frac{-1}{f'(x_0)}(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$
They will meet the $y$ axis when $x=0$. Therefore for the tangent line,
$$y=f(x_0)-f'(x_0)x_0$$
And for the normal,
$$y=f(x_0)+\frac{x_0}{f'(x_0)}$$
Perhaps you can apply this to your problem?